# Hover on a `before` element not working a expected with TailwindCSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I have this site https://jstech.vercel.app/ and I am having an issue with the `hover` effect of the `before` element on the navigation bar.

If you open this on screen wider that 768px, you will the navbar with the current URL having a blue underline. When you hover on the other nav items, they get a grey underline. However, I am getting the grey underline on the current page URL also & this is not what I want.

I have styled this with Tailwind and the classes applied are as below.

```
class={`relative flex items-center p-2 pl-1 pr-3  before:absolute before:bottom-0 before:left-0 before:w-full before:h-1 before:bg-accent before:rounded before:opacity-0 before:ease-in-out before:duration-300 hover:before:opacity-100 hover:before:bg-gray-300 ${aboveText ? 'hover:before:bg-gray-400' : ''} ${$page.url.pathname === item.url ? 'before:opacity-100 hover:before:bg-accent' : ''} `}
```

As you can see, `${$page.url.pathname === item.url ? 'before:opacity-100 hover:before:bg-accent' : ''}` I am controlling the opacity of the `before` element which is working just fine. But the `hover:before:bg-accent` is not working ('accent` is the theme color name for blue).

What am I doing wrong? How do I achieve the effect where the bottom border (the `before` element) has the blue color even on hover for the current page? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is having two classes that apply the same property with the same variant, namely `hover:before:bg-gray-300`, `hover:before:bg-gray-400` (when `aboveText` is truthy) and `hover:before:bg-accent` (when `$page.url.pathname === item.url` is truthy).

Consider consolidating these classes so that only one class is on the element at any one time, like:

```js
let hover = 'hover:before:bg-gray-300';
if ($page.url.pathname === item.url) {
  hover = 'hover:before:bg-accent';
} else if (aboveText) {
  hover = 'hover:before:bg-gray-400';
}

…

class={`… hover:before:opacity-100 ${hover} ${$page.url.pathname === item.url ? 'before:opacity-100' : ''} `}
```

Comment: The solution isn't working for me. Navigation bar hides after the user has scrolled down the page a bit & appears as soon as the user tries to scroll back up with the text behind the Navigation bar blurred. Since the blurred text behind will be such that `bg-gray-300` is not good enough to show the highlight, hence I wanted to change it is `bg-gray-400` when the navigation is "above text". For the sake of simplicity, I removed `${aboveText ? 'hover:before:bg-gray-400' : ''}` completely & still `${$page.url.pathname === item.url ? 'before:opacity-100 hover:before:bg-accent'` doesn't work!

Comment: Strangely  if I change the color from `bg-accent` to another color (for eg: `bg-red-400`) like so `${$page.url.pathname === item.url ? 'before:opacity-100 hover:before:bg-red-400'`, that works!!!

Comment: Ensure you have removed all other classes of `hover:before:bg-<color>` in the class list and only set one color in the `hover` variable as described above.